# Get all items from html select list using ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, list

I have the following select list:

```
<select name="Context" id="Context" size="5">
<option>Context1</option>
<option>Context2</option>
<option>Context3</option>
<option>Context4</option>
<option>Context5</option>
</select>
```

I am using javascript to move the items of this select list up and down (this is working). I would like to feed the resulting order back to ASP.net using C#.

If I use the following line of code I get only the selected item, how do I get the whole list?

```
 string items = Request.Form["Context"];
```

Comment: You can get just value of selected item or items. It won't post the whole list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all items like this.

```
var ddlArray= new Array();
var ddl = document.getElementById('Context');
for (i = 0; i < ddl.options.length; i++) {
    ddlArray[i] = ddl .options[i].value;
}
```

Now pass this JavaScript array to your code behind.

Comment: Thanks for this. Passing this to the c# code behind is the problem. I can't seem to do this using the HiddenField. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I used the following to send the data to the code beind:

HTML/ASP: <input type="hidden" value="" id="ContextVals" name="ContextVals" />
Javascript: document.getElementById("ContextVals").value = ddlArray;
ASP.Net C#: Request.Form["ContextVals"]

Answer (score 1):

One answer is to modify the `select` to make it a `ListBox` and then access it programattically on the server:

```
<asp:ListBox runat="server" name="lstContext" id="lstContext" size="5">
    <asp:ListItem>Context1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Context2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Context3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Context4</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Context5</asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
```

Note that I renamed it `lstContext` as calling it `Context` will cause build failures (due to sharing a name with the existing `Context` object).

Then in your code, to access the values in the order they appear:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lstContext.Items.Count; i++)
{
    string item = lstContext.Items[i].Value;
    // Do something with it
}
```

Your `javascript` should still work on the `ListBox` as it does for the `select`, so this should remain unaffected.

Comment: I have previously implemented the listbox solution but found it was very slow as it was calling back to the server every time an item was moved up/down. I need to be able to move the items using Javascript on the client end. I tried getting Javascript to move items in a Listbox but had no luck. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

create a hidden field (runat=server) and store the shuffled <options> into the hidden field; You can access content of hidden field at server side by `string itemsOrderedChanged = Request.Form[<HiddenFieldId>];`

Comment: I have tried storing it as a hidden field a few different ways but can never access it in the ASP. Do you have any further information on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

try to pass JavaScript value to hidden field like this .

```
var hidden=document.getElementById('hidValue');
var string strValues="";
for(var i=0i<ddlArray.Length;i++){
 strValues+=ddlArray[i]+",";
}

hidden.value=strValues;
```

And in page_load or what_ever event get this string and split it.

```
protected HtmlControls.HtmlInputHidden hidValue;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   dynamic hiddenValue = hidValue.Value;
   string [] arr=hiddenValue.Split(",");
}
```