# How to get selected value of a dropdown list that populated by JQuery in ASP.NET?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I used JQuery AJAX to fill a DropDownList (select) without postback.

How can I get the value of last item that added to the DropDownList in ASP.NET C#?

I used this code:

Client side code after adding new item to the DropDownList:

```
$("#my_list").prop('selectedIndex', 0);
```

Server Side code:

```
string last_item_added=my_list.value; // returns the one before last!
```

for example this is my list before using AJAX to add new item :

```
<select id="my_list">
 <option value="92">i3</option>
 <option value="91">i2</option>
 <option value="90">i1</option>
</select>
```

and after adding new item:

```
<select id="my_list">
 <option value="93">i4</option>
 <option value="92">i3</option>
 <option value="91">i2</option>
 <option value="90">i1</option>
</select>
```

I want to get value "93" in server side but it returns "92" when I use this code:

```
string last_item_added=my_list.value; // returns the one before last! in this case 92
```

Comment: could you please explain your question more?

Comment: Please describe your problem : wrong behavior vs expected behavior , error messages, ...

Comment: There is no error. I using JQuery to add option to the select(dropdown) list. I want to get the value of last option added in the list in server side(C#) but it returns the one before last when I submit the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get value of last child using jQuery by:

   $('#itemid option:last-child').val();
2. Pass this value to server code (webapi controller, web service etc.) by using jQuery ajax POST.

Comment: there is no way to get this value without AJAX (with postback) ?

Comment: This post will give you idea how to do it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881075/get-all-items-from-html-select-list-using-asp-net-c-sharp

Comment: Actually you can just set your method as webmethod and pass this value to existing void or function by jQuery ajax.

Comment: thank you,This code works good. string item = Request.Form["my_list"];